# How to get total cost per hotel and transfer per 8 days by sql query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-design, erd

**Problem**

How to get total cost per hotel and transfer per 8 days by sql query ?

**Details**

8 days = 7 nights

meaning 8 days = 7 days accommodation per hotel

because last day he take flight not stay in hotel .

**Result i need to get it**

[image]

I use following query :

```
;with cte_HotelPrice
as
(
select 
T6.HotelPrice,
T4.HotelID,
T5.HotelName,
T3.DetailsDurationID from package T 
inner join StartPackage T1 on T.PackageId=T1.PackageId
inner join packageduration T2 on T.PackageId=T2.PackageId
inner join (SELECT *, RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PackageDurationsId ORDER BY Days) 
    FROM DurationDetails) T3 on T2.PackageDurationsId=T3.PackageDurationsID
inner join DayDetails T4 on T3.DetailsDurationID=T4.DetailsDurationID
left join Hotel T5 on T4.HotelID=T5.HotelID
cross apply (select HotelPrice from HotelPrice where HotelID=T4.HotelID and FromDate<=DATEADD(day, T3.RN - 1, T1.StartDate) and ToDate>=DATEADD(day, T3.RN - 1, T1.StartDate)) T6
)
,TransferPrice as
(
select 
ttd.Price,
dds.DetailsDurationID
from package p 
inner join StartPackage s on p.PackageId=s.PackageId
inner join packageduration pd on p.PackageId=pd.PackageId
inner join (SELECT *, RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PackageDurationsId ORDER BY Days) 
    FROM DurationDetails) dd on pd.PackageDurationsId=dd.PackageDurationsID
inner join DayDetails dds on dd.DetailsDurationID=dds.DetailsDurationID
left join TransferType tt on dds.TransferTypeID=tt.TransferID
cross apply (select Price from TransferPeriod where TransferTypeID=dds.TransferTypeID and FromDate<=DATEADD(day, dd.RN - 1, s.StartDate) and Todate>=DATEADD(day, dd.RN - 1, s.StartDate)) ttd
)
select 
S4.HotelID,S4.HotelName, S.PackageName, S1.StartDate, S1.EndDate, 
sum(S4.HotelPrice) AS cost,
sum(S5.Price) as transfercost 
from package S 
inner join StartPackage S1 on S.PackageId=S1.PackageId
inner join packageduration S2 on S.PackageId=S2.PackageId
inner join DurationDetails S3 on S2.PackageDurationsId=S3.PackageDurationsID
left join  cte_HotelPrice S4 on S3.DetailsDurationID=S4.DetailsDurationID
left join  TransferPrice S5 on S3.DetailsDurationID=S5.DetailsDurationID
GROUP BY S4.HotelID, S4.HotelName,S.PackageName, S1.StartDate, S1.EndDate
```

my sample data found in this fiddle

http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=0096a903948a93c1269e931328648be2

**Update original post**

query below for answer 1 
not calculate value for transfer correctly
it give me 1300 as transfer cost
but correct is 700

**SampleData**

```
USE [NileTraveltest]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[DayDetails]    Script Date: 23/07/2017 1:46:54 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DayDetails](
    [DayDetailsID] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [DetailsDurationID] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [HotelID] [int] NULL,
    [TransferTypeID] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_DayDetails] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [DayDetailsID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[DurationDetails]    Script Date: 23/07/2017 1:46:54 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DurationDetails](
    [DetailsDurationID] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [PackageDurationsID] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Days] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_DurationDetails] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [DetailsDurationID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Hotel]    Script Date: 23/07/2017 1:46:54 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Hotel](
    [HotelID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [HotelName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Rating] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Product] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [HotelID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[HotelPrice]    Script Date: 23/07/2017 1:46:54 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[HotelPrice](
    [HotelPriceID] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [FromDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [ToDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [HotelPrice] [decimal](18, 0) NULL,
    [HotelID] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_ProductPrice] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [HotelPriceID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Package]    Script Date: 23/07/2017 1:46:54 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Package](
    [PackageID] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [PackageName] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [Duration] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Resident] [tinyint] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Package] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [PackageID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[PackageDuration]    Script Date: 23/07/2017 1:46:54 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PackageDuration](
    [PackageDurationsID] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [PackageID] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [PackageDuration] [int] NULL,
    [NightCounts] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_PackageDuration] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [PackageDurationsID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[StartPackage]    Script Date: 23/07/2017 1:46:54 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[StartPackage](
    [StartID] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [PackageID] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [StartDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [EndDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [TotalCost] [decimal](18, 0) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_StartPackage] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [StartID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[TransferPeriod]    Script Date: 23/07/2017 1:46:54 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TransferPeriod](
    [TransferDataID] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [FromDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [Todate] [datetime] NULL,
    [Price] [decimal](18, 0) NULL,
    [TransferTypeID] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_TransferPeriod] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [TransferDataID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[TransferType]    Script Date: 23/07/2017 1:46:54 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TransferType](
    [TransferID] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [TransferType] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_TransferType] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [TransferID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
INSERT [dbo].[DayDetails] ([DayDetailsID], [DetailsDurationID], [HotelID], [TransferTypeID]) VALUES (N'DDD01', N'DD01', 1, N'T01')
INSERT [dbo].[DayDetails] ([DayDetailsID], [DetailsDurationID], [HotelID], [TransferTypeID]) VALUES (N'DDD02', N'DD02', 1, NULL)
INSERT [dbo].[DayDetails] ([DayDetailsID], [DetailsDurationID], [HotelID], [TransferTypeID]) VALUES (N'DDD03', N'DD03', 1, NULL)
INSERT [dbo].[DayDetails] ([DayDetailsID], [DetailsDurationID], [HotelID], [TransferTypeID]) VALUES (N'DDD04', N'DD04', 1, NULL)
INSERT [dbo].[DayDetails] ([DayDetailsID], [DetailsDurationID], [HotelID], [TransferTypeID]) VALUES (N'DDD05', N'DD05', 1, NULL)
INSERT [dbo].[DayDetails] ([DayDetailsID], [DetailsDurationID], [HotelID], [TransferTypeID]) VALUES (N'DDD06', N'DD06', 1, NULL)
INSERT [dbo].[DayDetails] ([DayDetailsID], [DetailsDurationID], [HotelID], [TransferTypeID]) VALUES (N'DDD07', N'DD07', 1, NULL)
INSERT [dbo].[DayDetails] ([DayDetailsID], [DetailsDurationID], [HotelID], [TransferTypeID]) VALUES (N'DDD08', N'DD08', 2, N'T02')
INSERT [dbo].[DayDetails] ([DayDetailsID], [DetailsDurationID], [HotelID], [TransferTypeID]) VALUES (N'DDD09', N'DD01', 2, N'T01')
INSERT [dbo].[DayDetails] ([DayDetailsID], [DetailsDurationID], [HotelID], [TransferTypeID]) VALUES (N'DDD10', N'DD02', 2, NULL)
INSERT [dbo].[DayDetails] ([DayDetailsID], [DetailsDurationID], [HotelID], [TransferTypeID]) VALUES (N'DDD11', N'DD03', 2, NULL)
INSERT [dbo].[DayDetails] ([DayDetailsID], [DetailsDurationID], [HotelID], [TransferTypeID]) VALUES (N'DDD12', N'DD04', 2, NULL)
INSERT [dbo].[DayDetails] ([DayDetailsID], [DetailsDurationID], [HotelID], [TransferTypeID]) VALUES (N'DDD13', N'DD05', 2, NULL)
INSERT [dbo].[DayDetails] ([DayDetailsID], [DetailsDurationID], [HotelID], [TransferTypeID]) VALUES (N'DDD14', N'DD06', 2, NULL)
INSERT [dbo].[DayDetails] ([DayDetailsID], [DetailsDurationID], [HotelID], [TransferTypeID]) VALUES (N'DDD15', N'DD07', 2, NULL)
INSERT [dbo].[DayDetails] ([DayDetailsID], [DetailsDurationID], [HotelID], [TransferTypeID]) VALUES (N'DDD16', N'DD08', NULL, N'T02')
INSERT [dbo].[DurationDetails] ([DetailsDurationID], [PackageDurationsID], [Days]) VALUES (N'DD01', N'PD01', N'DAY1')
INSERT [dbo].[DurationDetails] ([DetailsDurationID], [PackageDurationsID], [Days]) VALUES (N'DD02', N'PD01', N'DAY2')
INSERT [dbo].[DurationDetails] ([DetailsDurationID], [PackageDurationsID], [Days]) VALUES (N'DD03', N'PD01', N'DAY3')
INSERT [dbo].[DurationDetails] ([DetailsDurationID], [PackageDurationsID], [Days]) VALUES (N'DD04', N'PD01', N'DAY4')
INSERT [dbo].[DurationDetails] ([DetailsDurationID], [PackageDurationsID], [Days]) VALUES (N'DD05', N'PD01', N'DAY5')
INSERT [dbo].[DurationDetails] ([DetailsDurationID], [PackageDurationsID], [Days]) VALUES (N'DD06', N'PD01', N'DAY6')
INSERT [dbo].[DurationDetails] ([DetailsDurationID], [PackageDurationsID], [Days]) VALUES (N'DD07', N'PD01', N'DAY7')
INSERT [dbo].[DurationDetails] ([DetailsDurationID], [PackageDurationsID], [Days]) VALUES (N'DD08', N'PD01', N'DAY8')
INSERT [dbo].[DurationDetails] ([DetailsDurationID], [PackageDurationsID], [Days]) VALUES (N'DD09', N'PD03', N'DAY1')
INSERT [dbo].[DurationDetails] ([DetailsDurationID], [PackageDurationsID], [Days]) VALUES (N'DD10', N'PD03', N'DAY2')
INSERT [dbo].[DurationDetails] ([DetailsDurationID], [PackageDurationsID], [Days]) VALUES (N'DD11', N'PD03', N'DAY3')
INSERT [dbo].[DurationDetails] ([DetailsDurationID], [PackageDurationsID], [Days]) VALUES (N'DD12', N'PD03', N'DAY4')
INSERT [dbo].[DurationDetails] ([DetailsDurationID], [PackageDurationsID], [Days]) VALUES (N'DD13', N'PD03', N'DAY5')
INSERT [dbo].[DurationDetails] ([DetailsDurationID], [PackageDurationsID], [Days]) VALUES (N'DD14', N'PD03', N'DAY6')
INSERT [dbo].[DurationDetails] ([DetailsDurationID], [PackageDurationsID], [Days]) VALUES (N'DD15', N'PD03', N'DAY7')
INSERT [dbo].[DurationDetails] ([DetailsDurationID], [PackageDurationsID], [Days]) VALUES (N'DD16', N'PD03', N'DAY8')
INSERT [dbo].[Hotel] ([HotelID], [HotelName], [Rating]) VALUES (1, N'Hilton', N'***')
INSERT [dbo].[Hotel] ([HotelID], [HotelName], [Rating]) VALUES (2, N'Movenpick', N'**')
INSERT [dbo].[Hotel] ([HotelID], [HotelName], [Rating]) VALUES (3, N'BasmaHotel', N'***')
INSERT [dbo].[HotelPrice] ([HotelPriceID], [FromDate], [ToDate], [HotelPrice], [HotelID]) VALUES (N'HP01', CAST(0x0000A6EE00000000 AS DateTime), CAST(0x0000A7A200000000 AS DateTime), CAST(20 AS Decimal(18, 0)), 1)
INSERT [dbo].[HotelPrice] ([HotelPriceID], [FromDate], [ToDate], [HotelPrice], [HotelID]) VALUES (N'HP02', CAST(0x0000A7A300000000 AS DateTime), CAST(0x0000A85A00000000 AS DateTime), CAST(30 AS Decimal(18, 0)), 1)
INSERT [dbo].[HotelPrice] ([HotelPriceID], [FromDate], [ToDate], [HotelPrice], [HotelID]) VALUES (N'HP03', CAST(0x0000A6EE00000000 AS DateTime), CAST(0x0000A7A200000000 AS DateTime), CAST(30 AS Decimal(18, 0)), 2)
INSERT [dbo].[HotelPrice] ([HotelPriceID], [FromDate], [ToDate], [HotelPrice], [HotelID]) VALUES (N'HP04', CAST(0x0000A7A300000000 AS DateTime), CAST(0x0000A85A00000000 AS DateTime), CAST(40 AS Decimal(18, 0)), 2)
INSERT [dbo].[HotelPrice] ([HotelPriceID], [FromDate], [ToDate], [HotelPrice], [HotelID]) VALUES (N'HP05', CAST(0x0000A6EE00000000 AS DateTime), CAST(0x0000A7A200000000 AS DateTime), CAST(50 AS Decimal(18, 0)), 3)
INSERT [dbo].[HotelPrice] ([HotelPriceID], [FromDate], [ToDate], [HotelPrice], [HotelID]) VALUES (N'HP06', CAST(0x0000A7A300000000 AS DateTime), CAST(0x0000A85A00000000 AS DateTime), CAST(60 AS Decimal(18, 0)), 3)
INSERT [dbo].[Package] ([PackageID], [PackageName], [Duration], [Resident]) VALUES (N'P02', N'AlexaPackage', N'8,15', 0)
INSERT [dbo].[Package] ([PackageID], [PackageName], [Duration], [Resident]) VALUES (N'P03', N'Amon', N'8', 1)
INSERT [dbo].[PackageDuration] ([PackageDurationsID], [PackageID], [PackageDuration], [NightCounts]) VALUES (N'PD01', N'P02', 8, 7)
INSERT [dbo].[PackageDuration] ([PackageDurationsID], [PackageID], [PackageDuration], [NightCounts]) VALUES (N'PD02', N'P02', 15, 14)
INSERT [dbo].[PackageDuration] ([PackageDurationsID], [PackageID], [PackageDuration], [NightCounts]) VALUES (N'PD03', N'P03', 8, 7)
INSERT [dbo].[StartPackage] ([StartID], [PackageID], [StartDate], [EndDate], [TotalCost]) VALUES (N'SD01', N'P02', CAST(0x0000A7A000000000 AS DateTime), CAST(0x0000A7A700000000 AS DateTime), CAST(210 AS Decimal(18, 0)))
INSERT [dbo].[StartPackage] ([StartID], [PackageID], [StartDate], [EndDate], [TotalCost]) VALUES (N'SD02', N'P03', CAST(0x0000A7A300000000 AS DateTime), CAST(0x0000A7AA00000000 AS DateTime), NULL)
INSERT [dbo].[TransferPeriod] ([TransferDataID], [FromDate], [Todate], [Price], [TransferTypeID]) VALUES (N'TD01', CAST(0x0000A6EE00000000 AS DateTime), CAST(0x0000A7A200000000 AS DateTime), CAST(200 AS Decimal(18, 0)), N'T01')
INSERT [dbo].[TransferPeriod] ([TransferDataID], [FromDate], [Todate], [Price], [TransferTypeID]) VALUES (N'TD02', CAST(0x0000A7A300000000 AS DateTime), CAST(0x0000A85A00000000 AS DateTime), CAST(300 AS Decimal(18, 0)), N'T01')
INSERT [dbo].[TransferPeriod] ([TransferDataID], [FromDate], [Todate], [Price], [TransferTypeID]) VALUES (N'TD03', CAST(0x0000A6EE00000000 AS DateTime), CAST(0x0000A7A200000000 AS DateTime), CAST(200 AS Decimal(18, 0)), N'T02')
INSERT [dbo].[TransferPeriod] ([TransferDataID], [FromDate], [Todate], [Price], [TransferTypeID]) VALUES (N'TD04', CAST(0x0000A7A300000000 AS DateTime), CAST(0x0000A85A00000000 AS DateTime), CAST(300 AS Decimal(18, 0)), N'T02')
INSERT [dbo].[TransferType] ([TransferID], [TransferType]) VALUES (N'T01', N'from airport to hotel')
INSERT [dbo].[TransferType] ([TransferID], [TransferType]) VALUES (N'T02', N'From Hotel to parking')
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[DayDetails]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_DayDetails_DurationDetails] FOREIGN KEY([DetailsDurationID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[DurationDetails] ([DetailsDurationID])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[DayDetails] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_DayDetails_DurationDetails]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[DayDetails]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_DayDetails_Hotel] FOREIGN KEY([HotelID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Hotel] ([HotelID])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[DayDetails] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_DayDetails_Hotel]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[DayDetails]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_DayDetails_TransferType] FOREIGN KEY([TransferTypeID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[TransferType] ([TransferID])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[DayDetails] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_DayDetails_TransferType]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[DurationDetails]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_DurationDetails_ProgramDuration] FOREIGN KEY([PackageDurationsID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[PackageDuration] ([PackageDurationsID])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[DurationDetails] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_DurationDetails_ProgramDuration]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[HotelPrice]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_HotelPrice_Hotel] FOREIGN KEY([HotelID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Hotel] ([HotelID])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[HotelPrice] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_HotelPrice_Hotel]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PackageDuration]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_PackageDuration_Package] FOREIGN KEY([PackageID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Package] ([PackageID])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PackageDuration] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_PackageDuration_Package]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[StartPackage]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_StartPackage_Package] FOREIGN KEY([PackageID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Package] ([PackageID])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[StartPackage] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_StartPackage_Package]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TransferPeriod]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_TransferPeriod_TransferType] FOREIGN KEY([TransferTypeID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[TransferType] ([TransferID])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TransferPeriod] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_TransferPeriod_TransferType]
GO
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will output the desired result but not sure if this is optimized or is aligned with your requirements. I just edited your select statement, didn't bother to check on the ctes.

```
SELECT  S4.HotelID ,
        S4.HotelName ,
        S.PackageName ,
        S1.StartDate ,
        S1.EndDate ,
        SUM(S4.HotelPrice) AS cost ,
        TransferCost
FROM    package S
        INNER JOIN StartPackage S1 ON S.PackageId = S1.PackageId
        INNER JOIN packageduration S2 ON S.PackageId = S2.PackageId
        INNER JOIN DurationDetails S3 ON S2.PackageDurationsId = S3.PackageDurationsID
        LEFT JOIN cte_HotelPrice S4 ON S3.DetailsDurationID = S4.DetailsDurationID
        OUTER APPLY ( SELECT    SUM(Price) AS TransferCost ,
                                HotelId
                      FROM      TransferPrice
                      WHERE     S4.HotelID = HotelID
                      GROUP BY  HotelID
                    ) tp
WHERE   S4.HotelId IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY S4.HotelID ,
        S4.HotelName ,
        S.PackageName ,
        S1.StartDate ,
        S1.EndDate ,
        TransferCost;
```

EDIT - for your new sample data, your CTE - TransferPrice returns 4 records which sums to 1000. Is there any reason why it shouldn't be 1000? I'm not familiar with the business requirement.

```
Price  DetailsDurationID
200    DD01
200    DD01
300    DD08
300    DD08
```

Update - Please see new query; also added HotelID to your CTE and now we have the transfer cost that you like. Cost column changed since transfer was charged to Hotel1 for day 8, which is what you like to achieve i guess.

[image: New Query]

Comment: thank you for reply it give me exactly result what i need for hotel cost but transfer cost is wrong

Comment: can you see image above only transfer cost is wrong if transfer cost is correct the all problem solved

Comment: It shows 500 from "Result i need to get it" section of your post and this query returns 500 as well. May i have the sample data that you are using?

Comment: yes according to my sample transfer cost is 500 but this will sum all transfer on table meaning if i have more package it will sum another package also

Comment: 500 is correct because i test only one package have 8 days but suppose in my database that i have more than one package

Comment: Please provide samples so i can help. Also note that i only edited your query based on your sample so there might have been some different conditions.

Comment: I attached my sample data above the query you give me in answer 1 post calculate hotel cost correct but transfer cost not correct

Comment: see the result i get according to you query as following https://i.stack.imgur.com/aKnYR.jpg

Comment: image link i attached in comments is result of implement query in answer 1 post to sample data i attached in last of original post

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/R4Fxa.jpg in this link i show how i use my business requirment if you need more clear ask without any problem

Comment: @user3223372 i suggest you add a HotelID in DDD08  and DDD16 in your TransferPrice CTE so we can use that reference for joining; customer will be coming from the Hotel anyway. I added an update to my answer.